# Is there any constraint in SQL where I add a value that is a foreign key to one table, it removes that value(primary key) from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables defined as:

dealership_inventory(vin, dealer_id, price, purchase_date)

where vin is the PK and dealer_id is the FK

transactions(transaction_id, dealer_id, customer_id, vin, cpurchase_date, price)

where transaction_id is PK and dealer_id,customer_id, and vin are FKs

Whenever I add a new transaction to the transactions table with an insert statement, I would like to remove that tuple with matching vin from the dealership_inventory table. Is this possible with some type of constraint?

Comment: I think you're looking for a trigger, not a constraint. FYI though with your current table structure you can't delete a "vin" in dealership_inventory since it's a FK on transactions

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do the removal of the VIN number from the inventory table.  Instead, if you want to find out whether a vehicle be still available, just use an exists query, e.g.

```sql
SELECT di.*
FROM dealership_inventory di
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM transactions t
    WHERE t.vin = di.vin
);
```

If, at some later point, the inventory table gets bogged down with items no longer available, you can run a batch job which moves these sold items to another table.